# Reducing after GROUP and COUNT in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a table in which I am trying to find the number of occurrences of an identifier

I begin by loading the table

```
a = LOAD 'table' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
```

then reduce the columns

```
b = FOREACH a GENERATE col1, col2, col3, col4;
```

I group the result on col1 because it holds the ID I am looking count occurrences of

```
c = GROUP b BY col1;
```

Then count the number of elements under each grouping

```
d = FOREACH c GENERATE COUNT(b), b.col1;
```

the result is

```
(1,{(111)})
(1,{(116)})
(2,{(118),(118)})
(2,{(122),(122)})
(2,{(125),(125)})
(1,{(134)})
(2,{(136),(136)})
(2,{(153),(153)})
(1,{(153)})
```

The second element in each row is the ID, repeated for the number of times it occurs.  How might I eliminate this bag and instead only have the count and ID tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d = FOREACH c GENERATE COUNT(b), b.col1;

-->

d = FOREACH c GENERATE COUNT(b), group;